# If $f(x)$ is analytic and non-negative, does convergence of $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ imply $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, analytic-functions

It is well known that improper integrals don't have to satisfy $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ in order for $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ to converge, for instance $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$. It is also possible to construct such non-negative $f(x)$, and even continuous and non-negative, by taking $f(x)$ to be $0$ everywhere except for triangular spikes with appropriate converging areas.

I was wondering whether we can get such $f(x)$ which is smooth or even analytic. It seems clear that it should be possible to modify the triangular spikes example and get such a smooth $f(x)$ by using bump functions. However, what if we wish for $f(x)$ to be analytic? Bump functions no longer come to the rescue.

To summarize: does there exist a non-negative $f(x)$ which is analytic in $[a,\infty)$ and such that $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ converges, but such that $f(x)$ does not converge to $0$ at infinity?

Comment: I might be wrong, but: Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}.$ Let $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n^2(x-n)).$ I think we can show this converges uniformly on any bounded interval, and its integral on the whole real line converges because it is $\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^2}.$ But $m\in\mathbb Z$ gives $g(n)>1.$ Essentially, this is a sum of thinner and thinner normal bumps to $1$ at each $n,$ and $e^{-n^4(x-n)^2}\to 0$ fast enough to ensure convergence of the sum. You might try others, like $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$ Then you might need something faster than $n^2$ as the factor to ensure convergence.

Comment: That certainly gives a positive continuous $g$ example, but I'm not sure if it is analytic.

Comment: But any positive continuous function where the integral does not converge has to have an $\epsilon>0$ and an increasing sequence $x_n\to\infty$ with all $f(x_n)>\epsilon.$ And implicitly, the function needs to be close to $f(x_n)$ in narrower and narrow intervals around $x_n,$ or the integral will not converge. So this is the usual way to construct a counterexample.

Comment: If we can show our sum converges uniformly on a sequence of bounded open subsets of the complex plane whose union contains the entire real line, then we have that this function is analytic. I would not be surprised if we could do this, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @Thomas the function is analytic as $|e^{-n^4(z-n)^2}|=e^{-n^4\Re ((z-n)^2)}$ and for any $a$ real we can discard the at most two integers closest to it so $\min |a-n| \ge 1$ for the rest and then for all $z$ in the ball of radius $1/3$ around $a$ we have $\Re ((z-n)^2) \ge 1/3$, hence the series converges uniformly there

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Neat idea! So we can use normal bumps as sort of nearly-bump functions in the analytic category. Thank you.

Comment: How about this one?
$$
f(x) = \left(\sin^2(x)\right)^{x^2},\quad x>0
$$where it is clearly "analytic"

Comment: @GEdgar Clever! I didn't imagine it could be done with a simple expression like this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment (without proofs as those can be found in literature) that gives some idea about the complexity of this problem: the result is true if $f$ is the restriction of an entire function of order at most $1$ and finite type - and then it is true in a more general setting, namely that if $f$ has order at most one and is of finite type if it has order $1$ and if $\int_0^{\infty}|f(x)|^pdx<\infty$ for some $p >0$, then $|f(x)| \to 0, x \to \infty$.

(here we can reformulate the condition on $f$ as there is $c>0$ st $|f(z)|e^{-c|z|} \le M$ for all $z$ and some $M >0$)

On the other hand, Carleman approximation theorem implies that for any positive continuous function $g(x)>0, x \in \mathbb R$ (or $x \in I$ any interval), there is an entire function $f$ st $0< g(x)/2 < f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ (or $x \in I$). This clearly shows that the result fails in general even for analytic functions on $(a, \infty)$ that are restrictions of entire functions in the plane

As asked in the comments a few references; first for the case of an entire function of order at most one, the general result is in the [Paley-Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) circle of ideas and can be found for example in [Boas Entire Functions](https://www.elsevier.com/books/entire-functions/philip-boas/978-0-12-374582-8) Theorem 6.7.1 p 98

For example if $f^2$ is integrable on the line, the result follows directly from Paley-Wiener and Riemann-Lebesgue and of course if $f$ only integrable on the line, the result above implies $f^2$ integrable and more generally $f^p$ integrable for all $p>1$ since $f^p(x) \le f(x)$ for large enough $|x|$

The Carleman approximation theorem states that for any continuous function $\psi(x)$ on $\mathbb R$ (or some interval on the line and even more general sets in the plane) and any error function $E(x)>0$ there, one can find an entire function $F$ st $|F(x)-\psi(x)| < E(x), x \in \mathbb R$; applying this with $E=3g/4, \psi=g/4$ gives the result mentioned here - more generally one can interpolate any $0<h<g$ continuous on the line with such an $F$ using $E=(h+g)/2, \psi=(g-h)/2$

A simple (pretty much writing down some Taylor series to get the result for $\psi=0$ when we can actually say more and get an entire non-vanishing anywhere in the plane $F$ st $0<F(x)<E(x)$ on the line), and a few algebraic and integral manipulations) direct proof of the result and actually generalized to $\mathbb R^n$ is in the paper [Uniform Approximations by Entire Functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02789974) by Stephen Scheinberg, while a more general approach including results for other sets than intervals on the line can be found in the book [Lectures on Complex Approximations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4814-9) by D Gaier ch IV,3 p 149 and on

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me find references for Carleman approximation theorem and for the claim in the first paragraph?

Comment: added references per request

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two related problems that one might want to consider at the same time as this one.

> **Problem 1.** Suppose that $ f $  is continuous on  $ [0,\infty) $  and that the improper integral $ \int_{0}^\infty f(x)\,dx $  converges. Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $ f $  so that  $ f(x) \to 0 $  as  $ x\to \infty .$

> **Problem 2**. Suppose that  $ f $  is Riemann integrable on every bounded interval contained in  $ [0,\infty) $  and that the improper integral  $ \int_{0}^\infty f(x)\,dx $  converges. Find necessary and sufficient conditions on  $ f $  so that  $ f(x) \to 0 $  as  $ x\to\infty $.

The well-known answer to the first problem  is *uniform continuity*.

An answer to the second problem is given in this elementary paper:

> R. B. Kelman and T. J. Rivlin. Conditions for Integrand of an
> Improper Integral to be Bounded or Tend to Zero.  The American
> Mathematical Monthly. Vol. 67, No. 10 (Dec., 1960), pp. 1019-1022.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!

Comment: Link to the article: https://doi.org/10.2307/2309243